# Split Cookie in headers

Tags: c#, parsing, cookies

I have the following Cookies in headers

> Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=cm3bg4muwin1vmbovc1esjy3; host=SCANDICWEB101; ieAlertDisplay=true; scandic_lb_cookie=1702298890.0.0000; s_sv_sid=110733906247;

This is my code to get the first one

```
var sessionId = webResponse.Headers["Set-Cookie"].Split(';')
                   .First(s => s.StartsWith("ASP.NET_SessionId="));
```

I tried to get the `host`, `scandic_lb_cookie` and the rest as well, but I couldnt figure out a way to do it, could you suggest me some ideas to get them?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly there are faster solutions, but following should work:

```
string source = cookie.Substring(8); // remove the "Cookie: "
var parts = source.Split(';')
                .Where(i => i.Contains("=")) // filter out empty values
                .Select(i => i.Trim().Split('=')) // trim to remove leading blank
                .Select(i => new { Name = i.First(), Value = i.Last() });
```

Then you can use them like:

```
foreach(var val in parts)
{
    string name = val.Name;
    string value = val.Value;
}
```

Or if you like it as a `Dictionary<string, string>`:

```
string source = coockie.Substring(8); // remove the "Cookie: "
var parts = source.Split(';')
                .Where(i => i.Contains("="))
                .Select(i => i.Trim().Split('='))
                .ToDictionary(i => i.First(), i => i.Last());
```

and then

```
string host = parts["host"];
```

See complete and working LINQPad example [HERE](http://pastebin.com/MDTzPbD0).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to iterate over cookie properties. Check [HttpWebResponse Cookie property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.cookies.aspx) and [How To: Get and Set Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dd920298%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) on MSDN. There is no need to do any complex string operation.

```
    private void ReadCookies()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://gmail.com");
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        //Console.WriteLine(response.Headers.ToString());
        //Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode.GetHashCode());

        CookieCollection IncomingCookies = response.Cookies;
        Console.WriteLine("Listing out {0} cookies received.", IncomingCookies.Count);
        foreach(Cookie cookie in IncomingCookies)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", cookie.Name, cookie.Value);
        }
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Please avoid link only answers as they would lose their value if the linked pages were to become unavailable (even though you have pointed to MSDN pages). Your answer would be better if you can add some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
var sessionId = webResponse.Headers["Set-Cookie"]
    .Split(';')
    .Where(s => s.StartsWith("scandic_lb_cookie="));
```